# Is ReferentialJDOStateManager not used in DataNucleus 4.x?

Tags: datanucleus, isis

I'm working with Apache Isis, attempting to update to DN 4.x but have a question about the `ReferentialJDOStateManager` in DataNucleus.
The `JDOStateManager` extended this class in DN 3.x but it is not present in DN 4.x

Affected class in Isis -
`public class JDOStateManagerForIsis extends ReferentialJDOStateManager implements StateManager, ObjectProvider`

I do see this class -
    `org.datanucleus.state.ReferentialStateManagerImpl`

I thought this might be the appropriate replacement, but if I extend `ReferentialStateManagerImpl`, there are problems...

The problem I encounter when extending the new class -
`ReferentialStateManagerImpl` extends `StateManagerImpl`. Which extends
`AbstractStateManager<Persistable>`

The current `JDOStateManagerForIsis` is setup to handle `PersistenceCapable` objects rather than `Persistable` objects.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PersistenceCapable` is not used by DataNucleus v4.x AFAIK; that was the old JDO-specific bytecode enhancement contract that they no longer use, now using DN-own `Persistable`.
I also see that each StoreManager can define which StateManager/ObjectProvider it is using, and the RDBMS plugin specifies **`ReferentialStateManagerImpl`**